# regexp check for & ( ) and repeating letters

Tags: javascript, regex

i work in javascript and like to check if my text has some signs. I'd like to check if my text has ( ) and & letters or it has repeating letters in it. Some examples:

> **test** - has multiple t
>
> **tes&t** - has &
>
> **test(test)** - has ( and ), multiple t and twice 'e' letter
>
> **test&(test** - has & and ( and multiple t and e
>
> **test&(&t** - has multiple t, multiple & and (
>
> **tesra** - this one doesnt fits any patterns

I've already made something like this:

```
if ((/(\w+)(?=\1)/g).test(str)) alert('multiple signs')
```

but it only counts multiple signs if they are one after another so 'teest' would fit pattern and test wouldnt. Can anybody help me? I never could understand all those regexp features :(
It can be divided in two regexp.

Thanx in advance

Comment: then in your opinion what would be best to match complicated patterns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it, though it might not be very efficient (since it is not anchored):

```
(?:[&()]|(\w)[^\1]*\1)
```

An alternative would be to simply iterate over the characters, inspect and count them:

```
function contains_multiple_chars(str, extra) {
    var chars = {};
    for(var i = 0,l = str.length; i < l;i++) {
        var c = str.charAt(i);
        if(c in chars || c in extra) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            chars[c] = 1;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

var multiple = contains_multiple_chars(str, {'(': 1, ')': 1, '&': 1});
```

(I admit the function name does not fit very well)

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add a `.*` to your lookahead.

```
(\w)(?=.*\1)|[()&]
```

See it [here on regexr](http://regexr.com?31n4i)

I also added an alternation with a character class to include your requested letters `()&`

If you want only letters (ASCII) instead of `\w` use a character class

```
([a-zA-Z])(?=.*\1)|[()&]
```

Comment: it work on regexr but unfortunatelly (and i dont know why - it doesnt work in javascript. thank you for trying to help